# applying a R NGA package function to an ffdf in R

Tags: r

I have just started using R to try and carry out a hazard analysis. Essentially I need to carry out a numerical integration, obtain some parameters and apply a complex function to each event.

I have used the ff and ffbase package as my computer slows up drastically as the number of scenarios increases. This works well up to a point.

Essentially the steps I am doing are as follows:
- Create a ffdf of all event combinations
- For all these events work out the different metrics that the ground motion prediction equation (GMPE) will need.
- Apply the (GMPE) function from the R NGA package using the rupture metrics calculated as inputs.

And this is where it goes wrong, as you will see from my code below I have written a loop function which applies the NGA function acceptably, but once it gets to about a few 100000 scenarios it gets snarled up and takes so long!!

The question is how do I apply this NGA function for each event or row of the ffdf so it will work efficiently for say 50,000,000 or more events. I was thinking about ffapply but struggle with understanding how to use it!! and cannot find examples.

The code I have is shown below, it may be agricultural but I am new to R. Any help will be really appreciated!!! Thanks in advance

R code is as follows:

```
#Create Variables to be combined
#Define Epicentral Distance
dRepi<-20
Repimax<-200
Rep<-ff(seq(dRepi/2, Repimax, by=dRepi))
#Define angle to epicenter
dang<-pi[1]/8
Anglemax<-2*pi[1]-dang
Angle<-ff(seq(0, Anglemax, by=dang))
#Define Magnitude
dmag<-0.1
Mmax<-7.5
Mmin<-5
Mag<-ff(seq(Mmin+dmag/2, Mmax-dmag/2, by=dmag))
#Define Epsilon
de<-0.5
emax<-3
emin<--3
e<-ff(seq(emin, emax,by=de))
#Define Fault Strike Angle
dtheta<- pi[1]/6
thetamax<- 2*pi[1]
thetamin<- 0
theta<-ff(seq(thetamin, thetamax-dtheta,by=dtheta))

#Create All Possible Event Combinations
Scenarios<-expand.ffgrid(e, Mag, Rep, Angle, theta)
colnames(Scenarios)<-c("Epsilon", "Magnitude", "EpiDistance", "EpiAngle", "theta")
#Number individual events
Nevs<-nrow(Scenarios)
Nevs#Display no. of events
Scenarios$EvNo <- ffdfwith(Scenarios, 1:Nevs)

#Calculate Rupture Metrics
Scenarios$Arup <- ffdfwith(Scenarios[c("Magnitude")], 10^(-3.42+0.9*Magnitude))
Scenarios$Wrup <- ffdfwith(Scenarios[c("Magnitude")], 10^(-0.76+0.27*Magnitude))
Scenarios$Lrup <- ffdfwith(Scenarios[c("Magnitude")],    10^(-3.42+0.9*Magnitude)/10^(-0.76+0.27*Magnitude))
Scenarios$Zhyp <- ffdfwith(Scenarios[c("Magnitude")], 5.63+0.68*Magnitude)
Scenarios$Ztor <- with(Scenarios[c("Magnitude")], ifelse((5.63+0.68*Magnitude-0.6*10^(-0.76+0.27*Magnitude)>0),( 5.63+0.68*Magnitude -0.6*10^(-0.76+0.27*Magnitude)),0))
Scenarios$Rx <-ffdfwith(Scenarios[c("EpiDistance", "EpiAngle", "theta")],abs(EpiDistance*sin(theta-EpiAngle)))
Scenarios$Rjba <- with(Scenarios[c("EpiDistance", "EpiAngle","Lrup","theta")],ifelse(((-   EpiDistance*sin(EpiAngle)*Lrup*sin(theta))+(-EpiDistance*cos(EpiAngle)*Lrup*cos(theta))<=0),( EpiDistance),0))
Scenarios$Rjbb <- with(Scenarios[c("EpiDistance", "EpiAngle","Lrup","theta")],ifelse(((Lrup*sin(theta))^2+(Lrup*cos(theta))^2<=-   EpiDistance*sin(EpiAngle)*Lrup*sin(theta)+-EpiDistance*cos(EpiAngle)*Lrup*cos(theta)),(((EpiDistance*sin(EpiAngle)+Lrup*sin(theta))^2+(EpiDistance*cos(EpiAngle)+Lrup*cos(theta))^2)^0.5),0))
Scenarios$Rjbc <- with(Scenarios[c("EpiDistance", "EpiAngle","Lrup","theta","Rjba","Rjbb")],ifelse((Rjba+Rjbb>0),0,( ((EpiDistance*sin(EpiAngle)+(((-EpiDistance*sin(EpiAngle)*Lrup*sin(theta))+(-EpiDistance*cos(EpiAngle)*Lrup*cos(theta)))/((Lrup*sin(theta))^2+(Lrup*cos(theta))^2))*Lrup*sin(theta))^2+(EpiDistance*cos(EpiAngle)+(((-EpiDistance*sin(EpiAngle)*Lrup*sin(theta))+(-EpiDistance*cos(EpiAngle)*Lrup*cos(theta)))/((Lrup*sin(theta))^2+(Lrup*cos(theta))^2))*Lrup*cos(theta))^2)^0.5
```

)))
    #Potentially simplify using Scenarios$Rjbc <- with(Scenarios[c("Rx","Rjba","Rjbb")],ifelse((Rjba+Rjbb>0),0,Rx)

```
Scenarios$Rjb <- ffdfwith(Scenarios[c("Rjba", "Rjbb", "Rjbc")],Rjba+Rjbb+Rjbc)
Scenarios$Rrup <-ffdfwith(Scenarios[c("Rjb", "Ztor")],(Rjb^2+Ztor^2)^0.5)
Scenarios$AziRjba<-with(Scenarios[c("Rjba","EpiDistance", "EpiAngle","Lrup","theta")],ifelse(Rjba>0,(180/pi[1])*acos((-   EpiDistance*sin(EpiAngle)*Lrup*sin(theta)+-EpiDistance*cos(EpiAngle)*Lrup*cos(theta))/(Lrup*EpiDistance)),0))
Scenarios$AziRjbb<-with(Scenarios[c("Rjbb","Rx")],ifelse(Rjbb>0,180*asin(Rx/Rjbb)/pi[1],0))#Error message here NaNs produced!!!
Scenarios$AziRjbc<-with(Scenarios[c("Rjbc")],ifelse(Rjbc>0,90,0))
Scenarios$Azi <- ffdfwith(Scenarios[c("AziRjba", "AziRjbb", "AziRjbc")],AziRjba+AziRjbb+AziRjbc)

#Define Parameters for CY NGA model
M<-Scenarios$Magnitude
Rjb<-Scenarios$Rjb
epsilon<-Scenarios$Epsilon
Vs30<-300
VsFlag<-0
rake<-180
AS<-0
Rrup<-Scenarios$Rrup
Rx<-Scenarios$Rx
Ztor<-Scenarios$Ztor
Zhyp<-Scenarios$Zhyp
W<-Scenarios$Wrup
Azimuth<-Scenarios$Azi

#Define For Loop - Problem though with looping over large no. of rows!!!!
PGA = (rep(NA,Nevs))
for(i in 1:nrow(Scenarios)){
PGA[i]=Sa.cy(M[i],Rjb[i], Vs30, VsFlag, epsilon[i], T=0, Rrup[i], Rx[i],
      dip = 90, W[i], Ztor[i], Z1.0 = NA, rake, Frv = NA,
      Fnm = NA, Fhw=NA, Azimuth[i], Zhyp[i], AS)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general advice. Use `ffseq` from package ffbase instead of `ff(seq(..?` As in `ffseq(dRepi/2, Repimax, by=dRepi)`

Regarding your last code, if `Sa.cy` is vectorised, you could use chunk on your ffdf and apply `Sa.cy` on the data from the chunk as in.

```
PGA = (rep(NA,Nevs))
mychunks <- chunk(Scenarios)
for(myblock in mychunks){
  ScenariosINRAM <- Scenarios[myblock, ]
  PGA[seq(min(myblock), max(myblock))] <- Sa.cy(ScenariosINRAM$Magnitude, ScenariosINRAM$Rjb, Vs30, VsFlag, ScenariosINRAM$Epsilon, T=0, 
                                                ScenariosINRAM$Rrup, ScenariosINRAM$Rx,
                                                dip = 90, ScenariosINRAM$Wrup, ScenariosINRAM$Ztor, Z1.0 = NA, rake, Frv = NA,
                                                Fnm = NA, Fhw=NA, ScenariosINRAM$Azi, ScenariosINRAM$Zhyp, AS)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I think that could work however I have just tried to run it and I had lots of errors like this:1: In if (is.na(M) == TRUE | M < 0) stop("M must be a positive number") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. Can you see if that code runs on your machine?? Thanks

Comment: That error looks like it comes from the Sa.cy function and not from ff so you should better ask the maintainer of the `NGA` package

Comment: Ok, Running it with my standard loop it's fine just quite slow, is there any other way you can think of that would speed it up? I was just looking at the foreach package

Comment: You should not use your standard loop, this will be terribly slow. You should use chunk and apply your Sa.cy function on your data in RAM as shown. You might consider using sapply(1:nrow(ScenariosINRAM), FUN=function(x) yourSa.cy function call) inside the chunk loop if Sa.cy is not vectorised.

Comment: Ok, would you mind sending me some code to try utilising that. Thanks.

Comment: I have managed to get it working using map ply, and chunk. It is still slow but quicker than other loop and maintains speed on large datasets.Thanks